# Extracting number of bits in a macroblock from VVC VTM reference software

Tags: c++, hevc, bitstream

[Final:Result after calculating and displaying the difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PwGM.png)I am new to VVC and I am going through the reference software's code trying to understand it. I have encoded and decoded videos using the reference software. I want to extract the bitstream from it, I want to know the number of bits there are in each macroblock. I am not sure which class I should be working with, for now I am looking at, `mv.cpp`, `QuantRDOQ.cpp`, and `TrQuant.cpp`.

I am afraid to mess the code up completely, I don't know where to add what lines of code. [Start: Result after calculating and displaying the difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEumW.png)
P.S. The linked pictures are after my problem has been solved, I attached these pictures because of my query in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, `getNumBins()` is not supported by the CABAC estimator. So you should make sure you call it "only" during the encoding, and not during the RDO.

This should do the job:

```
if (isEncoding())
    before = m_BinEncoder.getNumBins()

coding_unit( cu, partitioner, cuCtx );

if (isEncoding())
{
    after = m_BinEncoder.getNumBins();
    diff = after - before;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I'll try and let you know if it works.

Comment: I tried it out and it works, I tried to print out the difference because I wanted to know the number of bits in a macroblock. I added the line: cout<<"The difference is: "<<diff<<endl; after the second if statement. I have attached screenshots of the result in my original question as links. Should I consider the final difference as the number of bits in a macroblock or is each difference the number of bits in each macroblock? Because I also get negative values. @Mosen

Comment: could you also suggest how to get the macro block information from the decoder side? And the motion vectors? I want partially decode to get the macro block and motion vectors. Looking forward to your suggestion. @Mosen

Comment: As far as I know, you can't use this solution at the decoder side.

Comment: Alright, thanks for letting me know. Sorry for the late reply, I didn’t realize I got a reply. How would you suggest extracting the motion vectors and the quantization parameters at the encoder side? I think we can get the from CABACWriter.cpp as well. @Mosen

Comment: I figured out how to extract the quantization parameters. I extracted them from EncGOP.cpp. Now I am working on extracting the motion vectors.

Comment: Same principle applies on motion vectors. Except that you should be dealing with some other functions e.g. `cu_pred_data`, `merge_flag`, `merge_data`, `mvp_flag`, `affine_flag`, `mvd_coding` etc.

Comment: Thank you. I think I got the motion vectors as well but not sure if they are correct. Now I am looking at getting the number of ctu (width x height) so I can have a 2-d array output where I can see which MV refers to which CTU.

Answer (score 0):

The simpleset solution that I'm aware of is at the encoder side.

The trick is to compute the difference in the number of written bits "before" and "after" encoding a Coding Unit (CU) (aka macroblock). This stuff happens in the `CABACWriter.cpp` file.

You should go to to `coding_tree()` function, where `coding_unit()` function is called, which is responsible for context-coding all syntax elementes in the current CU.
There, you may call the function `getNumBins()` twice: once before and once after `coding_unit()`. The difference of the two value should do the job for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion! I called the getnumbins () function and tried to print out the values in CABACWriter.cpp but I get this error during compilation: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type Exception: ERROR: In function "getNumBins" in /Users/mac/documents/VVCSoftware_VTM-master/source/Lib/EncoderLib/BinEncoder.h:254: Not supported @Mosen

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion! I called the getnumbins () function and tried to print out the values in CABACWriter.cpp but I get this error during compilation: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type Exception: ERROR: In function "getNumBins" in /Users/mac/documents/VVCSoftware_VTM-master/source/Lib/EncoderLib/BinEncoder.h:254: Not supported @Mosen I tried replying but I don't know why I can't tag your name properly so I am not sure if you'll see this.